# Update the value of added rows in database by 1 using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have a table with three fields

```
id (primary key / auto incremented)
groupId
text
```

my problem is when i insert multiple rows through form the whole group of rows should get same groupId (incremented by 1 in last added groupId).
I dont know how to do it.
Please help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should really leave your code or its hard to respond but I expect you are looking for something like...

```
$this->db->select_max('group_id','max_group_id');
$query = $this->db->get('whatever_your_table_is_called');

//this increments the highest group id by 1
$next_group_id = $query->result_array()[0]['max_group_id']+1;

//do your loop probably
foreach($group_of_users as $user){
   $data[]=array('group_id'=>$next_group_id,'text'=>$user['text_value'])
}

$this->db->insert_batch('whatever_your_table_is_called', $data);
```